# Importing Target installed Python Package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-lambda

I have some AWS Lambda python code. In this code I would like to use psycopg2 so I can do database queries. To do this I know that I need to install it to the local directory so I can upload it with the zip into the lambda function. So I have done this

```
pip install psycopg2 -t .
```

And that works, I now have the psycopg2 directory in the directory of my lambda code. I now just need to know how do I import psycopg2 in my python file. Jus tto be clear this his how the directory structure looks:

```
container_folder
-- lambda_function.py
-- psycopg2
---- // pscopg2 files are in here
```

**UPDATE: I have the import working. But I know get this error:**

libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I add the libpq files for use on Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to compile both psycopg2 and PostgreSQL from source and add it to the zip package. Here's a good tutorial for it:

https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2